# Using the MultiversX SDK for JavaScript (TypeScript), how to sign (and verify) an arbitrary message?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, multiversx

How to sign an arbitrary message (arbitrary sequence of bytes) using the **MultiversX SDK** for *JavaScript* / *TypeScript*?

Then, how to verify the signature?

Answer (score 1):

The code below is relying on the libraries `@multiversx/sdk-wallet` (v4) and `@multiversx/sdk-core` (v12).

Signing the message:

```
import { SignableMessage } from "@multiversx/sdk-core";
import { UserSigner } from "@multiversx/sdk-wallet";
import { promises } from "fs";

// First, load a wallet and create a UserSigner object:
const fileContent = await promises.readFile("alice.json", { encoding: "utf8" });
const walletObject = JSON.parse(fileContent);
const signer = UserSigner.fromWallet(walletObject, "password");

// Then, prepare and sign the message:
const message = new SignableMessage({ message: Buffer.from("hello") });
const serializedMessage = message.serializeForSigning();
const messageSignature = await signer.sign(serializedMessage);

// Output should be:
// Address of signer: erd1qyu5wthldzr8wx5c9ucg8kjagg0jfs53s8nr3zpz3hypefsdd8ssycr6th
// Signature: 561bc58f1dc6b10de208b2d2c22c9a474ea5e8cabb59c3d3ce06bbda21cc46454aa71a85d5a60442bd7784effa2e062fcb8fb421c521f898abf7f5ec165e5d0f
console.log("Address of signer:", signer.getAddress().bech32());
console.log("Signature:", messageSignature.toString("hex"));
```

The example above uses [Alice's test wallet](https://github.com/multiversx/mx-sdk-testwallets/blob/main/users/alice.json) (generally used for examples on MultiversX). The address (public key) of this wallet is `erd1qyu5wthldzr8wx5c9ucg8kjagg0jfs53s8nr3zpz3hypefsdd8ssycr6th`.

Verifying the message signature:

```
import { Address, SignableMessage } from "@multiversx/sdk-core";
import { UserVerifier } from "@multiversx/sdk-wallet";

const verifier = UserVerifier.fromAddress(Address.fromBech32("erd1qyu5wthldzr8wx5c9ucg8kjagg0jfs53s8nr3zpz3hypefsdd8ssycr6th"));
const message = new SignableMessage({ message: Buffer.from("hello") });
const serializedMessage = message.serializeForSigning();
const messageSignature = Buffer.from("561bc58f1dc6b10de208b2d2c22c9a474ea5e8cabb59c3d3ce06bbda21cc46454aa71a85d5a60442bd7784effa2e062fcb8fb421c521f898abf7f5ec165e5d0f", "hex");

// Output should be:
// Is signature correct? true
// Is signature correct? false
console.log("Is signature correct?", verifier.verify(serializedMessage, messageSignature));
console.log("Is signature correct?", verifier.verify(serializedMessage, Buffer.from(Array(64).fill(0))));
```

Extra notes and references:

- MultiversX uses the [Ed25519 algorithm](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to) to sign transactions. The same algorithm is used to sign arbitrary messages. However, the actual data being signed (see `serializeForSigning` and `serializedMessage` in the example above) is obtained as follows: `keccak256(SPECIAL_PREFIX_BYTES concat MESSAGE_LENGTH_AS_STRING_BYTES concat MESSAGE_BYTES)`.
- The **sdk-js cookbook**: https://docs.multiversx.com/sdk-and-tools/sdk-js/sdk-js-cookbook#signing-objects